# Why does a 1-knot spline regression have 3 coefficients?

Tags: count-data, splines, statsmodels

I've been learning about spline regressions, and I'm trying out a statsmodels negative binomial spline regression as a changepoint detector for a time series of count data.

I'm pretty confused about the coefficients of the model, and I'm hoping I might ask for some pointers.

I'm using the `statsmodels.api` GLM to fit the model.

```py
# set a possible knot location and run the model to see how it fits.
possible_knot = 5
basis_x = dmatrix(f"bs(count_index, knots=({possible_knot},), degree=1,  
                       include_intercept=True)", 
                  {"count_index": count_data.index}, return_type='dataframe')

spline_model = sm.GLM(count_data.weekly_counts, basis_x, 
                      family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=1.0)).fit()
```

As I understand it, this spline regression is fitting two different models with the data split at the "knot" location. There's only one regressor, the time variable. So I expect there would be only be two coefficients for the model (plus the intercept). But when I look at the `summary()` output, I see three coefficients pluss the intercept:

[image]

I see the intercept. But why are there *three* coefficients for my one-knot spline?

Is one of them the intercept for regression #2 in the spline? Or ... have I messed up somewhere else?

I'm confused about how to interpret these results since there are more coefficients than I know what to do with.

I've seen there are other questions about spline coefficients, but I think my question is more basic, and I haven't managed to understand how to apply those discussions here.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have the intercept twice, one explicit and one included in the spline `include_intercept=True`.  `df_model=2`, `df_residuals = nobs - 3`  indicates that the rank of your design matrix is 3 and not 4. The parameters when using IRLS should in this case be a `pinv` regularized solution.

Comment: thanks! I'm not familiar with `pinv`, but it seems like you're right - If I switch `include_intercept` to `False`, then I end up w/ a design matrix and coefficients taht look like what I'd expect. And there is an intercept in the summary, and an intercept is still included in the design matrix, even with `include_intercept=False` So perhaps I've misunderstood what "include_intercept" in statsmodels means

Comment: Spline basis function by default are "collinear" with a constant. `include_intercept=False` as part of the spline definition (not of the overall formula) specifies that the implicit intercept in the spline basis functions should be removed. This requires dropping one of the spline basis columns (or imposing an extra linear constraint which is not available if we want to encode the constraint in a non-singular design matrix)